# How to throw RuntimeException deliberately?

Tags: java, exception, apache-storm

Suppose my topology is this simple :

```
Spout --> Bolt A --> Bolt B --> Bolt C
```

And Bolt C stores the data in a datastore.

Now is it advisable to throw a RuntimeException whenever there is some Exception in storing data ? 
Something like  :

```
try {
    datastoreManager.insert(myData);
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

OR should I just throw a FailedException and let the topology retry that tuple ?

What should be a good practice ?

I didn't see any harm in deliberately throwing a RuntimeException here because when this happens , the current worker thread dies and since ACK was not received by the topology , the tuple will be re-tried on some other worker, resulting in the same overall output as by throwing a FailedException **except** for some enhanced load on the topology.

Answer (score 0):

Consider extending from RuntimeException

```
public DataException extends RuntimeException {
}

try {
    datastoreManager.insert(myData);
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new DataException(e);
}
```

Now the classes above in the call hierarchy can choose to catch this specific exception or let it propagate up.

Since this is unchecked you may want to add sufficient documentation in the java doc to let callers expect a RuntimeException

Answer (score 0):

You want to look a little deeper at the type of exception that is being thrown. If it's transient, like a connection error, you can throw a FailedException and let the topology replay it. However, you wouldn't want to do that with an error that will require someone's attention to fix. In that case you want to throw a custom error as suggested that provides enough information to fix the problem - http://bugroll.com/how-to-write-good-error-messages.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the requirements of your system and what is the right semantic. But I were you, I won't throw an exception. What I would do is: If an exception is thrown, I would catch that and save the identity ***and*** the state of `myData` into a persistent store (such as Apache kafka or JBoss HornetQ).

After you analyse what went wrong, you can reply your event.

Again, this could be not accepted if your system needs more strict semantic.